# Date and Permission Comparison

Tags: bash

I want to take the output of an ls on a directory and then store it in a text file. Which is done by this code below.

```
    ls -lt $search_path > date_verify.txt
```

After this, I would like to take a line of this text file like below, and compare the date listed to the actual date of the specific file. Same goes for the permission. I am wondering how am able to the date in the file and compare that date to the current date modified of the file itself. It would return True if they match and False if they don't. How can the dates be compared?

```
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 us000000 us000000        185 Jun 20 12:04 file1.txt
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What is the question? You're not asking one.

Comment: I am wondering how am able to the date in the file and compare that date to the current date modified of the file itself. It would return True if they match and False if they don't. How can the dates be compared?

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add this, and show what you've tried and how it specifically failed.

Comment: When taking the `ls -l` of a directory, it shows the date modified and the permissions.  This output and the current date modified and permissions would always match, unless something had changed in the small time it tool to run the script.

Comment: It is for an install, so one would be run before the install and one after, to make sure everything went smoothly.

Comment: You don't want to check dates. You want to compute something like an MD5 checksum for the file you are installing, then compare that against the checksum of the file that results from the installation process.

Comment: Also, you are basically trying to implement your own package manager. Don't bother; there are lots to choose from that have already solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a bad idea to parse ls, you could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$search_path"/* ; do
    seconds=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
    cmpdate=$(date -d @$seconds '+%Y-%m-%d')
    infiledate=$(something)
    if [ "$cmpdate" = "$infiledate" ] ; then
        echo "Hurray, dates match for $file"
    else
        echo "$file has a mismatch"
    fi
done
```

The '+%Y-%m-%d' is the format string. You should consult `man date` to get the date in the exact format that is in your file.
the `$(something)` should be replaced by a way to get the date from the file, probably involving something with `head`, `tail`, `grep` and/or `sed`.